# Optimised way of replacing strings with each other in SQL table

Tags: sql, t-sql, query-optimization

**Problem Statement:**
Looking for the optimised way of replacing strings with each other in SQL table with huge data and multiple cases.

**Consider, I have a table City**

[image]

I need to replace Bangalore with Delhi and Delhi with Bangalore and similarly there might be 'n' number of other cases.

I know that we can use casing in update to replace the data in the table. Is there a better way of doing it using Replace() function or anything else in the single update..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative would be to create a temporal table, something like

```
create table #tmpReplace(OriginalValue varchar(200), NewValue varchar(200))
```

and make an inner join with your table. The advantage is a much simpler update. The drawback, you still have to populate this table.

For example:

```
update yt
set yt.Name = tmp.NewValue
from dbo.YourTable yt inner join #tmpReplace tmp on tmp.Name = OriginalValue
```

Comment: [Temporal Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15). [Temporary Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#temporary-tables).

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, the easiest method would seem to be a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       CASE Name WHEN 'Bangalore' THEN 'Delhi'
                 WHEN 'Delhi' THEN 'Bangalore'
                 ...
                 ELSE Name
       END AS Name
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: if there are 'n' cases, then i have to write casing for 'n' number of times, is there any better way than this..?

Comment: Correct, @VishalIPatil . What ever method you use you're going to need to write them out. SQL Server can't read your mind. It doesn't know what needs to be swapped with what, *you* need to tell it.

Comment: as mentioned in the question, i know this can be achieved using casing in update. Just looking for an alternative as we are dealing with large amount of data and we are having some performance issue with this.

Comment: Alternative to *what* @VishalIPatil . An `UPDATE`?

Comment: Alternative to casing?

Comment: To do what, @VishalIPatil ? `CASE` is the most appropriate expression here.

Comment: @VishalIPatil Reading your comments, I don't know if that's clear: It fits all in one CASE expression. You can replace the ... with as many WHEN.. THEN blocks as you want.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating a derived table in the query with the "replacement" values:

```
update t
    set t.name = v.newvalue
    from t join
         (values ('Delhi', 'Bangalore'),
                 ('Bangalore', 'Delhi'),
                 . . . 
         ) v(oldvalue, newvalue)
         on v.oldvalue = t.name;
```